# SQL Server 2005 I get "The database is not accessible"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a computer working as a server with many SQL Server 2005 databases in it since two years ago.

Today, I don't know why, when I try to connect locally to any of the databases it gives me that error. It fails even if I'm logged in using Windows Authentication or as 'sa' user. It just wouldn't let me access the databases' info.

Could anybody explain me what's going on?

Comment: Probably not without a bit more information.

Comment: Bears: which kind of info would be useful for you to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know what was going on. I ended up rebooting the server and it all started working fine as always.

Comment: I'd still worry if it takes a reboot... which doesn't really make sense unless the DB was offline as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Database does not exist or it's offline etc.

First check, can you see the DB in the object explorer in SSMS?

Comment: I'm connecting to the server using the SSMS already. It shows me the database list but it wouldn't let me see their content and info.